# Send object in Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

All the other examples I've seen don't really end up working out well for me. I'm attempting to send/receive custom objects using Socket.IO. For example, let's say I have this object on both ends

```
function ExampleObject(data){
   this.data = data;
}
```

Then on the client side I do,

```
socket.emit('receiveObject', new ExampleObject("whatever");
```

On the server side, when I use

```
client.on('receiveObject', function (obj) {
    if(obj instanceof ExampleObject){
      process.stdout.write("Received example object");
    }else{
      process.stdout.write("Received something unknown");
    }
});
```

The problem is that instanceof is not working, though I am receiving the object. Does anybody know how I can do this? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

socket.io uses `JSON.stringify()` to serialize any object you pass it and `JSON.stringify()` just converts an object into plain JSON which does not include any info about what type of object it is or what methods it has.

When socket.io on the other end of the connection then uses `JSON.parse()` to turn it back into an object, you get just a plain Javascript object.  Thus `obj instanceof ExampleObject` will always be `false`.

The usual work-around is to add a property to your object that says what type of object it is and then use that property on the receiving end of things to either construct the right type of object or to use in your `if` statement.

Here's an example:

```
function ExampleObject(data){
   this.data = data;
   this.type = "ExampleObject";
}

socket.emit('receiveObject', new ExampleObject("whatever");
```

Then, on the other end:

```
client.on('receiveObject', function (obj) {
    if(obj.type === "ExampleObject"){
      process.stdout.write("Received example object");
    } else {
      process.stdout.write("Received something unknown");
    }
});
```

Or, you could actually construct the appropriate object on the receiving end:

```
function ExampleObject(data){
   if (typeof data === "object" && data.type === "ExampleObject") { 
       // construct from plain object
       Object.assign(this, data);
   } else {
       // construct from normal data object
       this.data = data;
       this.type = "ExampleObject";
   }
}

client.on('receiveObject', function (obj) {
    if (obj.type) {
        switch(obj.type) {
            case "ExampleObject":
                obj = new ExampleObject(obj);
                break;
            case "OtherObject":
                obj = new OtherObject(obj);
                break;
            default:
                console.error("Unsupported object type: ", obj.type);
                break;
        }
    } else {
        // just plain object
    }
    if (obj instanceof ExampleObject){
        process.stdout.write("Received example object");
    } else {
        process.stdout.write("Received something unknown");
    }    
});
```

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly - This is not the same answer.  It shows how to recreate the original type of object if that is an important part of the full solution.  And, the explanation is much more complete and thorough (in my opinion).  Stack Overflow encourages people to write the best and most complete answers possible.  This is just not a race for someone to include one possible short explanation.  People posting questions are looking for the best and most complete answer.  So, you downvoted me because my answer is more complete than yours and includes more possible ways to solve the problem?

Comment: No, I downvote because you don't encourage already supplied answer with more details, and posting logically same answer with some changed words - that's how I see this, if I'm not correct, downvote me too, I'm just tryin to help ppl and earn points, your answer is exact what I tho at first, but kept simplicity for the OP

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly - In my opinion, I offer a more complete solution than what you show. I thought it was worth posting an answer to share a method for getting back the original object type since it appears that is what the OP actually wants for the full solution (otherwise they wouldn't be attempting to send `ExampleObject` type in the first place).  You don't downvote answers here just because they offer a more complete solution than the first answer that appeared.  I provide an answer when I have something meaningful to add above/beyond answers already provided.

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly - It would be better for you to remove your downvote rather than me to downvote yours.  There's nothing wrong with your answer, it just doesn't cover as much of a solution as I thought was useful so I added my own answer.

Comment: Agree, but still I feel like I've been robbed tho

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly - Note, I show both how to switch on `obj.type` to to call the constructor AND I show how to create a constructor that can take either a plain object or the regular default parameter as its argument.  This is meaningful new solution content above what you provided as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io sends only plain javascript objects

---

When sending object via socket.io, they are serialized into JSON which does NOT retain the type of the object or any of the methods of the object. It only retains the properties of the object.

## workaround

Add custom property to `ExampleObject`

```
function ExampleObject(data){
   this.data = data;
   this._custom_flag = true;
}
```

Check it

```
client.on('receiveObject', function (obj) {
    if(obj._custom_flag){
      process.stdout.write("Received example object");
    }else{
      process.stdout.write("Received something unknown");
    }
});
```

Comment: True but it needs to check if custom flag exist and if data exist before trying to use them.

Comment: Sure, that's the point, you don't have any other option indeed